Simulation of vanes rotation with the help of wind
All day I try to rotate the arrow with the help of the wind, but I never succeed. The arrow starts to turn a little, but even then in the opposite direction...

An additional question would be how do I get rid of these cylindrical holders and place the arrow in some kind of bed / support that would allow the arrow to rotate under a gust of wind but not fall?
Thanx


This does not seem to be possible for now:

Rotation
Influence the rotation of particles with Dynamic Rotation. The option
is not relevant for other types of physics systems.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/123847
On the same page, YimingWu comments:
"...the best choice for you is to probably use geometry nodes to simulate the effect."
Does anyone have an idea how to approach to this?
